# Xeon Phi cannot execute binary file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04, xeon-phi

I am trying to execute a binary file on a xeon phi coprocessor, and it is coming back with "bash: cannot execute binary file". So I am trying to find how to either view an error log or have it display what's happening when I tell it to execute that is causing it not work. I have already tried `bash --verbose` but it didn't display any additional information. Any ideas?

Comment: This usually means that the executable was compiled for an incompatible operating system. `bash --verbose` doesn't help because it's the kernel that determines whether it can execute something, not bash.

Comment: Try using the `file` command to examine the program.

Comment: upon using the `file` command it output the following:
`ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x5716658b4548777cfbbac018225dee322b261efe, not stripped`

Comment: What is the actual command you're executing when you get that error?

Comment: originally I was executing `./program` but then switched to `bash program` when I tried to use `--verbose`

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify where you compiled your executable nor where you tried to execute from.
To compile a program on the host system to be executed directly on the coprocessor, you must either:

- if using one of the Intel compilers, add -mmic to the compiler
  command line
- if using gcc, use the cross-compilers provided with the MPSS
  (/usr/linux-k1om-4.7) - note, however, that the gcc compiler does not
  take advantage of vectorization on the coprocessor

If you want to compile directly on the coprocessor, you can install the necessary files from the additional rpm files provided for the coprocessor (found in mpss-/k1om) using the directions from the MPSS user's guide for installing additional rpm files.
To run a program on the coprocessor, if you have compiled it on the host, you must either:

- copy your executable file and required libraries to the coprocessor
  using scp before you ssh to the coprocessor yourself to execute the
  code.
- use the micnativeloadex command on the host - you can find a man page
  for that on the host.

If you are writing a program using the offload model (part of the work is done using the host then some of the work is passed off to the coprocessor), you can compile on the host using the Intel compilers with no special options.
Note, however, that, regardless of what method you use, any libraries to be used with an executable for the coprocessor will need themselves to be built for the coprocessor. The default libraries exist but any libraries you add, you need to build a version for the coprocessor in addition to any version you make for the host system.
I highly recommend the articles you will find under https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/programming-and-compiling-for-intel-many-integrated-core-architecture. These articles are written by people who develop and/or support the various programming tools for the coprocessor and should answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: What's below **does NOT answer the OP's question** - it is *one* possible explanation for the `cannot execute binary file` error, but **the fact that the error message is prefixed with `bash:` indicates that the binary is being *invoked* correctly (by bash), but is *not compatible* with the executing platform (compiled for a different architecture)** - as @Barmar has already stated in a comment.

Thus, while the following contains some (hopefully still somewhat useful) general information, it does not address the OP's problem.

---

*One* possible reason for `cannot execute binary file` is to **mistakenly pass a *binary* (executable) file** -- rather than a shell script (*text* file containing shell code) -- **as an *operand* (filename argument) to bash**.

The following demonstrates the problem:

```
bash printf # fails with '/usr/bin/printf: /usr/bin/printf: cannot execute binary file'
```

<sup>Note how the mistakenly passed binary's path prefixes the error message twice; If the first prefix says `bash:` instead, the cause is most likely not a problem of incorrect *invocation*, but one of trying to a invoke an *incompatible* binary (compiled for a different architecture).</sup>

**If you want bash to invoke a binary, you must use the `-c` option** to pass it, which allows you to specify an entire command line; i.e., the binary plus *arguments*; e.g.:

```
bash -c '/usr/bin/printf "%s\n" "hello"'  # -> 'hello'
```

If you pass a **mere binary *filename*** instead of a full path - e.g., `-c 'program ...'` - then a binary by that name must exist in one of the directories **listed in the `$PATH` variable** that bash sees, otherwise you'll get a `command not found` error.

If, by contrast,  the **binary is located in the *current* directory, you must prefix the filename with `./`** for bash to find it; e.g. `-c './program ...'`

Comment: Sounds like the problem is indeed one of _binary compatibility_, as @Barmar has already surmised (I've updated my answer to explain that my explanation won't solve your problem). Do you need _special builds_ of programs to run on Xeon Phi coprocessors? Can you currently run anything there?